Upgrade to 24.04.1 was not good. Is it reasonable to go back to 22.04 and wait or should I stick it out?
Will all or most the problems with 24.04.1 be resolved in some reasonable amount of time? I have not had this kind of experience previously so I am not aware of time frames.
OR
Is it reasonable to go back to 22.04 until such time 24.04 is "solid".

Ubuntu/Debian provide no tools to go backwards, so if its reasonable to go backwards will depend on what backup strategy you put in place, and how are we to know what.  You can go backwards via non-destructive re-install, but problems with doing that are package specific, so you'll need to perform that review yourself (ie. every program/package where data is important to you; we don't even know if you're asking about Server/Desktop which is basic details you've not provided, but review is package level! not product/release level)

It is unclear what "all or most the problems with 24.04.1" refers to, so the question seems unanswerable as currently written.

There was a problem with upgrading and Canonical decided to pause the upgrade process whilst it wqas addressed. That has now been completed with this comment "If you are affected by this issue, you can run apt install --fix-broken to remove the old kernel headers and make apt operational again." in this discourse post
